# vibrate notifications only when receiving emails from certain addresses?

Tags: email, notifications, vibration

Is it possible to set vibrate notifications when receiving emails from a list of email addresses but not when receiving emails that don't come from that list? Either using the default Gmail app on a 2.3.5 Android phone or something else.

I have a bunch of labels defined, but on the Gmail App I got the following menu: `Notification settings` with:
 `Email notifications [x]`
 `Labels to notify`

In `Labels to notify` I only have:

`Inbox` off
`Priority Inbox` Zeta, Always, Notify once for new emails

But I can't add more labels to this menu...

Answer (score 2):

With Gmail if you set up label, you can set different notification sound including vibration per label.

This means in Gmail.com first of all you've to create a filter to apply a label to email address you want different notification.

After that Open Gmail in your phone, go to Menu -> Settings -> Your email address -> Manage Label -> Select created label. Here set the desired notification scheme.

Comment: On 2.3.5 I can't see a `Label` option in the Gmail App settings. Maybe with a different name?

Comment: Can you see "Manage label" or something like that.

Comment: Nope. This is version 2.3.5.2

Comment: Unfortunately, 3 years later, this still appears to be the only way to do this. And the filter needs to be manually edited every time you want to add a new user, since Gmail filters can't use contact groups.