# Stop Gmail notifications when receiving email from particular sender

Tags: email, gmail

Is there any way to stop the Gmail app from popping up a notification if you get an email from a specific sender?

My specific case is that I get a lot of emails from a careers site that I'm not usually interested in reading immediately so don't need to be notified about them. There's a [related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21159/vibrate-notifications-only-when-receiving-emails-from-certain-addresses) on the site but this is asking for the opposite.

Answer (score 9):

From the Gmail web interface, create a rule to give it a *label* of your choice and skip the inbox. Then, from the Gmail Android app, change the settings for that label to not notify you.

In more detail, the first part is:

- Log into Gmail in a browser, and click the settings button (gear icon).
- Click the **Filters** tab, then **Create a new filter** at the bottom.
- Set the settings for the filter: in this case, use the **From** field.
- Click the search button (magnifying glass) to check your filter, or go straight to **Create a filter with this search**.
- Put a tick in the **Skip the inbox (Archive it)** checkbox, and another in **Apply the label** and choose the label you want or create a new one from the drop-down.
- Click **Create filter**.

Then, starting from the main screen (folder view) of the Gmail app:

- Click the overflow menu (three dots in the top-right)
- Choose **Manage labels**
- Choose the label you just set in the filter
- Make sure **Label notifications** is turned off.

Comment: I've done the first bit but the label hasn't appeared on the Gmail app yet (~5 minutes later). I'm assuming it just hasn't synced yet, I'll try again later and accept if it works. Thanks.

Comment: It still hasn't updated, any idea? Here's the image of my 'Manage Labels' in the app to show what's there: http://imgur.com/vM5y5zp

Comment: I'm sure why the label isn't syncing yet. If you look in the web interface, are there any mails with this label yet? Maybe it only shows up when the label is used. If that doesn't help, ask a new question. More people will see it, and someone else might have had the same problem.

Comment: I would like to control label notifications without having to skip the inbox. (I want these emails in my inbox, just without notifications, as I was able to do with Inbox's "bundles" concept.)